# Как заменить все значения в массиве по условию?

Tags: python, массивы, python-2.x, numpy

Возможно ли заменить в массиве одни значения на другие, например, все 4 на 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

Пример:

```
b = a.copy()
b[b==4] = 0
```

Comment: а если с возможностью создать новый массив, ну чтобы два была a - исходный, b - с измененными значениями?

Comment: @ManifestoMr, дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо) а может вы знаете как можно будет сделать 3д рисунок по этому массиву? сейчас объясню. в моем случае массив это набор высот, т.е координата Z, при этом я знаю координаты нижнего левого угола и и шаг с которым происходит движение по сетке как по X так и по Y

Comment: @ManifestoMr, советую задать новый вопрос с примером данных)

Answer (score 1):

```
np.where(a == 4, 0, a)
```

---

*Тест:*

```
In[1]: a = np.random.randint(1, 5, 20)
In[2]: a
```

> ```
> Out[2]: array([4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3])
> ```

```
In[3]: np.where(a == 4, 0, a)
```

> ```
> Out[3]: array([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3])
> ```